# JPA Entity Mapping Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have problem with JPA Entity Mappings. I have some classes:

ClassA

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {

private int id;

@OneToMany
private List<ClassB> listClassB;
}
```

ClassB

```
@Entity
public class ClassB {

private int id;

@ManyToOne
private ClassA classA;

@OneToMany
private List<ClassC> listClassC;
}
```

ClassC

```
@Entity
public class ClassC {

private int id;

@ManyToOne
private ClassB classB;

    private String code;
    private String name;

@OneToMany
private List<ClassD> listClassD;
}
```

ClassD

```
@Entity
public class ClassD {
    private int id;
    private Long value;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date finishDate;

@ManyToOne
    private ClassC classC;
}
```

Now, I want to have another entity that have all the property and association of ClassC, and have it's own property (the value is numbers of ClassD that related to Class C). When I use class inheritance like this:

ClassE

```
@Entity
public Class ClassE extends ClassC {

    // All ClassC properties

    private Long numberOfClassD;
}
```

It throw com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'pegawai0_.DTYPE' in 'field list'.
"Maybe" caused by missing Discriminator column. But in my case, I don't have discriminator column.

*** How to solved this issue ?***
Can I still use Class Inheritance? Or another way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: and have you tried setting the Inheritance strategy (of "C") to "JOINED"?

Comment: Do C&E have a relationship at the database level or only in Object model. If not, then see @MappedSuperclass: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AlanHay, the relationship only exist in Object model. And MappedSupperclass annotation solve the problem. I will post it in another answer, so anyone with same problem could find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alan Hay suggest in the comment, the ClassC and ClassE doesn't have any relationship in database. So, using @MappedSuperclass solve the problem.

I implement it this way:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public Class SuperClass {

    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private ClassB classB;

    private String code;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<ClassD> listClassD;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public Class ClassC extends SuperClass {

    // No Property

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public Class ClassE extends SupperClass {

    private String classECustomValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, both ClassC & ClassE have been marked with @Entity and hence the 'Table per class hierarchy' inheritance strategy is used. By default, the discriminator column name is 'DTYPE'.

You can just try it out with using 'Table per class' hierarchy strategy on 'ClassC'. The tables generated, however, would be much different from the 'Table per class hierarchy' though.

You might want to check which inheritance strategy you would need based on the domain model. This link would be good guide to that:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html